# How do you change the background color of a live tile at runtime?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to change the background color of a live tiles on my Windows 8 application at runtime. Is this possible? Does anybody have a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Background color is specified in app manifest. Thus it does not seems to be possible.

The same can be emulated by sending custom time at runtime with appropriate background image (for a color). This is quirky way, but my little mind can think of this approach only.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have already fixed the problem but I will post this info here, might be useful if someone come accross this thread.

For Primary Tile the answer from Bruno Lemos is correct.

**For Seconday Tiles** I would use TileUpdateManager.**CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile**(Tile2_ID).

Using TileNotifications and TileUpdaterManager works instantly to me.

Using the Tile templates you will have to modify some XML code from the template, but you could also download **NotificationsExtensions** NuGet package and do it this way:

```
var tile2 = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText01();
tile2.Branding = TileBranding.Name;
tile2.Image.Src = "ms-appx:///assets/Logo-transparent.png"; //Useful to have the same logo image with transparent background and other colors
tile2.TextHeading.Text = "Heading";
tile2.TextBody1.Text = "String1";
tile2.TextBody2.Text = "String2";
tile2.TextBody3.Text = "String3";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(tile2.ToString());
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(tile2_id);
updater.EnableNotificationQueueForSquare150x150(true); //enables up to 5 different tile *animations* for 150 square icon, can be enabled for other sizes too
updater.Update(new TileNotification(doc) { Tag = "1" });
```

The code above takes into account the SecondaryTile has been created previously.

You can see the different templates for icons here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.notifications.tiletemplatetype.aspx

You only have to change the line **TileContentFactory.CreateNAMEOFTEMPLATE** and fill the different string/image fields.

Info about **EnableNotificationQueue** to have more than 1 animation in the tile can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781199.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**For Primary / Default Tile**, you can do what @Tilak said: create tile images notifications and use `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update` to update it.

**For Secondary Tiles**, do the following:

1. In the app manifest, set the background color to "transparent"
2. In the app manifest, use images with transparent background
3. Now you can do that at runtime:

`var tile = new SecondaryTile("YOUR_TILE_ID");
tile.VisualElements.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red;
await tile.UpdateAsync();`

> The problem is: The background is not updating immediately and I don't
>   know why. But you can see the effect after sign out / sign in, for
>   example. (tested using windows 10)

So this answer is incomplete, but hopefully can give insights to people coming here from google, like me.

[@brunolemos](http://twitter.com/brunolemos)